# C# Console Keeps On Popping Up On Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms

When I run the following code, I want just my form to show up and not the console.  How can I get this to work this way?

```
namespace NameSpace1
{
    public class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you check your project properties? The output type may be set to 'Console Application' on the 'Application' tab.